# Reload client browser if a widget is added/removed or updated in Wordpress Customizer?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to figure out how to detect if a widget has been added/removed or updated in the Wordpress Customizer. And if a change is made, the clients browser should reload to show the changes automatically.

I have tried this:

```
jQuery(document).on('widget-updated widget-added', function(event){
   console.log('Widget change made!');
});
```

I get nothing in my console log, and I don't understand why. I have also tried MutationObserver, but I guess that won't work as the widget is not added on the client browser viewing the page.

The last solution I am looking at is to automatically observe the mysql database value of "sidebars_widgets" for changes, and if a change is made, reload the page.

What is the best approach for this?

Comment: There is no best approach to do that. Because there are various ways to solve and which solution is better or worse depends on many factors. On way would be to open a websocket for each client to your server and then you could inform each client that it has to update.

Comment: This announcement post about [Widget Customisation](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/17/live-widget-previews-widget-management-in-the-customizer-in-wordpress-3-9/) might help.

Comment: I have tried looking in to websockets, but I'm not sure I understand how to utilize it.
@DanielJames I read that before, that's where I found 'widget-updated widget-added' but I am not sure why it won't do anything at all.